# Separating this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a hard time understanding how to approach this problem.

$$2yy'+4=y^{2}+4x$$

I've converted it to the following form, but I don't know how I can separate the x and y's.

$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=y^{2}+4x-4$$

**Update:**
Okay, thanks for the tip on substitution. This is what I did.
$$2yy'+4=y^{2}+4x$$
$$u=y^2+4x$$
$$u'=2yy'+4$$
$$u'=u$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}=u$$
$$\int{u^{-1}}du=\int{1}dx$$
$$\ln{u}=x+c$$
$$u=e^{x+c}$$
$$y^2+4x=e^{x+c}$$
$$y=\sqrt{e^{x+c}-4x}$$
$$y=\sqrt{ce^{x}-4x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT...substitute $u=y^2$ and you will obtain a differential equation in $u$ and $x$ which is easily solved using an integrating factor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Bernoulli Differential Equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx). What you do is divide both sides by $2y$ to get $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac y2=(4x-4)y^{-1}$. From there, you can substitute $u=y^{1-(-1)}=y^2$ to convert this into a first order linear ordinary differential equation. I strongly suggest reading the entire article I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute!
$$y^2=u,\mspace{18mu} 2yy'=u'$$
$$u'-u=4x-4$$
$$u_h=c\cdot e^x$$
$$u_p=c(x)\cdot e^x, \mspace{18mu} c'=\int\dfrac{4x-4}{e^x}~dx=-4\cdot e^{-x}x$$
$$u=u_h+u_p=c\cdot e^x-4\cdot e^{-x}x$$
$$\vert y\vert=u^{1/2}=(c\cdot e^x-4\cdot e^{-x}x)^{1/2}$$